# Flexbox dislocating shared layout components in an ASP.NET MVC (FX) application

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, layout, flexbox

I have this `_Layout.cshtml` file that is shared amongst all views in my app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - HR Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" title="List View" class="links">
                    <img alt="List View" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/WVDOT.png")" style="width:60px; height:60px; margin-right: 10px">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("WC Inbox Forms", "Index", "WC_Inbox")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Employees", "Index", "Employees")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Archived", "Archive", "WC_Inbox")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Which provides the header and footer for pages and ends up looking like this:

[image: home]

However 1 page in the app needs to be kind of specifically styled so I chose to use flexbox and made this stylesheet which makes everything on the page with which I use this stylesheet look great:

```
.pageContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.title {
    display: flex;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

.Info {
    width: 70%;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.infobox {
    width: 30%;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.innerBox {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightyellow;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.title2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

However, ever since I added flexbox to this css sheet my navbar on only this page has been repositioned along with the footer being moved to the top of the page:

[image: mypage]

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? I'd prefer not to change the layout page if possible as it is being used successfully in every other page in the app. If you need it, here is the create page that that is in question (it is rather long):

```
@model HR_APP_V2.Models.WC_Inbox
<link href="~/Styles/FormCreate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

    <div class="pageContainer">
        <h3 class="title">Create a new Injury Form for @ViewBag.Name</h3>


        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        @Html.Hidden("EmployeeID", (object)ViewBag.EmployeeID)

        @Html.Hidden("Status", (object)ViewBag.Status)

        @Html.Hidden("fullName", (object)ViewBag.Name)

        <div class="container">
            <div class="Info">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.District, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownList("District", new List<SelectListItem>
                        {
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "District 1", Value="1"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "District 2", Value="2"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "District 3", Value="3"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "District 4", Value="4"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "District 5", Value="5"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "District 6", Value="6"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "District 7", Value="7"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "District 8", Value="8"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "District 9", Value="9"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "District 10", Value="10"  }
                        }, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Org_Number, "Org Number", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Org_Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "0025" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Org_Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-right:1%"><p style="color:#FF0000">*</p></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Hire_Date, "Hire Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hire_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Hire_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-right:1%"><p style="color:#FF0000">*</p></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Job_Title, "Job Title", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Job_Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Programmer Analyst" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Job_Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-right:1%"><p style="color:#FF0000">*</p></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Work_Schedule, "Work Schedule", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownList("Work_Schedule", new List<SelectListItem>
                        {
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "8 hours per day, 5 days per week", Value="8 hours per day, 5 days per week"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "8.5 hours per day, 5 days per week", Value="8.5 hours per day, 5 days per week"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "9 hours per day, 5 days per week", Value="9 hours per day, 5 days per week"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "10 hours per day, 4 days per week", Value="10 hours per day, 4 days per week"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "10 hours per day, 5 days per week", Value="10 hours per day, 5 days per week"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "10.5 hours per day, 4 days per week", Value="10.5 hours per day, 4 days per week"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "10.5 hours per day, 5 days per week", Value="10.5 hours per day, 5 days per week"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "11 hours per day, 4 days per week", Value="11 hours per day, 4 days per week"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "11 hours per day, 5 days per week", Value="11 hours per day, 5 days per week"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "12 hours per day, 4 days per week", Value="12 hours per day, 4 days per week"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "12 hours per day, 5 days per week", Value="12 hours per day, 5 days per week"  },
                        }, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Work_Schedule, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="infobox">
                <div class="innerBox">
                    <h4 class="title2">Employment information</h4>
                    <hr style="border:0px;border-top:1px solid black;width:75%;" />
                    <p>Information Related to the Employee's Position</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr style="border:0px;border-top:1px solid grey;width:75%;" />

        <div class="container">
            <div class="Info">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Injury_Date, "Injury Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Injury_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Injury_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-right:1%"><p style="color:#FF0000">*</p></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Injury_Time, "Injury Time", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Injury_Time, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "2:00pm" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Injury_Time, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-right:1%"><p style="color:#FF0000">*</p></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOT_12, "Injury Documented on DOT-12?", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownList("DOT_12", new List<SelectListItem>
                        {
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "Yes", Value="Yes"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "No", Value="No"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "DOT-12 Pending", Value="DOT-12 Pending"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "Not Applicable", Value="Not Applicable"  },
                        }, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Start_Time, "Start Time on Date of Injury", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Start_Time, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "8:00am" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Start_Time, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-right:1%"><p style="color:#FF0000">*</p></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Injured_Body_Part, "Injured Body Part", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Injured_Body_Part, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Forearm" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Injured_Body_Part, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-right:1%"><p style="color:#FF0000">*</p></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Side, "Which Side", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownList("Work_Schedule", new List<SelectListItem>
                        {
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "Left", Value="Left"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "Right", Value="Right"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "Both", Value="Both"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "Not Applicable", Value="Not Applicable"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "See Comments", Value="See Comments"  },
                        }, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Missing_Work, "Missing Work", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Missing_Work)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Missing_Work, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Return_to_Work_Date, "Return to Work Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Return_to_Work_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker" } })
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-right:1%"><p style="color:#FF0000">*</p></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Doctors_Release, "Doctor's Work Release Obtained? (Do not choose Yes unless you have the work release in hand; Send it to HR)", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownList("Doctors_Release", new List<SelectListItem>
                        {
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "Yes", Value="Yes"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "No", Value="No"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "Not Yet", Value="Not Yet"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "Not Treated", Value="Not Treated"  },
                        }, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Treatment, "Treatment Pursued/Scheduled?", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Treatment)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Treatment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Injury_Description, "Injury Description", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Injury_Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Injury_Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-right:1%"><p style="color:#FF0000">*</p></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Equipment, "Equipment", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Equipment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Equipment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Witness, "Name witnesses if any (If none, state no witnesses).", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Witness, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @cols = 40, @rows = 10 } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Witness, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Questioned, "If the injury is questioned, state why (If not questioned, say 'Not Questioned').", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Questioned, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Not Questioned" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Questioned, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Medical_History, "If there is a prior relevant medical history, mention what it is (If none known, state none known).", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Medical_History, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "None known" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Medical_History, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Inbox_Submitted, "Was this inbox submitted within 48 hours/2 business days of the injury date?", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownList("Inbox_Submitted", new List<SelectListItem>
                        {
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "Yes", Value="Yes"  },
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "No", Value="No"  },
                        }, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Inbox_Reason, "Reason", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Inbox_Reason, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Inbox_Reason, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments, "Comments", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comments, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="infobox">
                <div class="innerBox">
                    <h4 class="title2">Injury</h4>
                    <hr style="border:0px;border-top:1px solid black;width:75%;" />
                    <p>Enter Information About the Employee's Injury</p>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
        <hr style="border:0px;border-top:1px solid grey;width:75%;" />


        <div class="container">
            <div class="Info">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User_Email, "User Email", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User_Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "John.Doe@wv.gov" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User_Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-right:1%"><p style="color:#FF0000">*</p></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact_Email, "Contact Email", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact_Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact_Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-right:1%"><p style="color:#FF0000">*</p></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Specialist_Email, "Specialist Email", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Specialist_Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Specialist_Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-right:1%"><p style="color:#FF0000">*</p></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Optional_Email, "Optional Email", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Optional_Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Optional_Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Optional_Email2, "Optional Email 2", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Optional_Email2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Optional_Email2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Optional_Email3, "Optional Email 3", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Optional_Email3, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Optional_Email3, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Optional_Email4, "Optional Email 4", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Optional_Email4, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Optional_Email4, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="infobox">
                <div class="innerBox">
                    <h4 class="title2">Email</h4>
                    <hr style="border:0px;border-top:1px solid black;width:75%;" />
                    <p>Enter Your Email Address , a District Contact's Email Address, and an Occupational Safety Specialist's Email Address. Add Optional Email Addresses if you are submitting the form on behalf of the designated reporter and you want the designated reporter to receive a copy.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        }

        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>

    </div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Please provide a **minimal** reproducible example. There is to much going on in your code snippet

Comment: @johannchopin I shared the entire page just so you could see it if you need to, but it isn't necessary to understand the problem. If you feel that this isn't reproducible all you'd need to do would be to create an empty view in the out of the box ASP.Net MVC framework and add a div with display:flex without adding flex to the _layout.cshtml page that also comes out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.container` styles are causing the issues.

You are using `.container` in a few places, with your `FormCreate.css` (I am assuming the styles you posted are from that file)  `.container` styles overriding the global `.container` styles.

In your separate page, rename the `.container` class to something that doesn't already have styles, and update the styles to use that new class, and it should fix your issues.

**Alternatively** nest your .container styles under a parent `.pageContainer .container { // styles }` or `.form-horizontal .container { // styles }`

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea that would cause those issues. I've been scratching my head over this for days. I appreciate this so much!